# circshift using index values

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I was looking for a way to circshift using index values.

I know I can shift all values using the circshift command see below

```
a=[1:9]
b=circshift(a,[0,1])
```

But how do I shift every 3rd value over 1?
example:
**Note: variable `a` can be any length**

```
a=[1,2,30,4,5,60,7,8,90] %note variable `a` could be any length
```

I'm trying to get `b` to be

```
b=[1,30,2,4,60,5,7,90,8]  % so the values in the index 3,6 and 9 are shifted over 1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this with the standard usage of `circshift`. There are a couple of other ways that you could approach this. Here are just a few.

## Using `mod` to create index values

You could use `mod` to subtract 1 from the index values at locations `3:3:end` and add `1` to the index values at locations `2:3:end`.

```
b = a((1:numel(a)) + mod(1:numel(a), 3) - 1);
```

**Explanation**

Calling `mod 3` on `1:numel(a)` yields the following sequence

```
mod(1:numel(a), 3)
%  1     2     0     1     2     0     1     2     0
```

If we subtract 1 from this sequence we get the "shift" for a given index

```
mod(1:numel(a), 3) - 1
%   0     1    -1     0     1    -1     0     1    -1
```

Then we can add this shift to the original index

```
(1:numel(a)) + mod(1:numel(a), 3) - 1
%   1     3     2     4     6     5     7     9     8
```

And then assign the values in `a` to these positions in `b`.

```
b = a((1:numel(a)) + mod(1:numel(a), 3) - 1);
%   1    30     2     4    60     5     7    90     8
```

## Using `reshape`.

Another option is to reshape your data into a `3 x N` array and flip the 2nd and 3rd rows, then reshape back to the original size. **This option will only work if `numel(a)` is divisible by 3**.

```
tmp = reshape(a, 3, []);

% Grab the 2nd and 3rd rows in reverse order to flip them
b = reshape(tmp([1 3 2],:), size(a));
```

Comment: I notice if I added another value to `a` it doesn't seem to work is there a work around?  I updated the question to add a note that variable `a` can be of any length.

Comment: @RickT Really? The first solution doesn't work? It should work for any size of `a`. The second solution *is* dependent on the size. I have added a statement to clarify this.

Comment: I get an error message with the first one.
error: Invalid resizing operation or ambiguous assignment to an out-of-bounds array element
This is what I tried

Comment: @RickT Can you tell me what the error message is? Also what size is `a`?

Comment: This is what I tried 
`a = [1,2,30,4,5,60,7,8,90,999]
b((1:numel(a)) + mod(1:numel(a), 3) - 1) = a;`

Comment: I'm using octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab ... there maybe a bug I'll have to investigate more

Comment: @RickT Ah ok that makes sense. I actually just updated the first answer to one that should work (uses referencing rather than assignment which is what Octave was complaining about)